# Magento Zend Email No exception but not sent

Tags: php, email, magento, zend-framework

since a week i'm having this issue on Magento 1.9, i've created a little script to test the sending of some of our emails,
Using this sintax:

$mail = new Zend_Mail();

```
$mail->setBodyText("Hello");
$mail->setFrom("TestSubject", "TestSubject");
$mail->addTo("Email@email.com", "TestSubject");
$mail->setSubject("Test Email");

try {
    $mail->send();
    echo "Email Sent";
} catch(Exception $ex) {
    echo ' Cant send Email '.$ex;
}
```

This is not throwing exception and neither sending Emails to the subject,
Any Idea's about what could it be?

Kind regards

Comment: PHP will only *know* if the email has been sent to the mail server successfully **not** whether it has actually been sent - nor anything after that.

Comment: Your saying that the issue is probably on the Smtp server that is receiving the requests from Magento but he's not capable of sending them?